# How to install appcelerator titanium on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, install-from-source, ide

I downloaded the available [zip file](http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/titanium.linux.gtk.x86.zip) which -from its name- seems to be gtk,

and when trying to run TitaniumStudio as explained in the installation guide

```
run the TitaniumStudio executable
```

I get this error msg

```
There is no application installed for executable files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

I don't know how to get titanium studio up and running as the instructions isn't clear enough!!

Comment: Are you on 64-bit Ubuntu, or 32-bit?

Comment: I'm on 32-bit ubuntu

Comment: Is the file's executable permissions bit set? It sounds like you're trying to open the file in Nautilus, and that bit is not set.

Comment: That seems right @dobey I changed the permissions it was like "-rw------- 1 uxe 62814 Aug 31 01:13 TitaniumStudio
" ,
and it launched the program :), can you write it as an answer to mark it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the file permissions are not correct and you are attempting to open the file in Nautilus, so it wants to open it rather than run it. You need to ensure the +x bit is set on the file.